# Landscape View Box Placement

Tags: swiftui, ios16

I have a landscape view with the screen split between two boxes: Current Categories and Available Categories. Tapping a category icon in the Available Categories box will move the category icon to the Current Categories box. And tapping a category icon in the Current Categories box move the icon to the Available Categories box.

This all works fine in portrait mode but I'm having some trouble with box placement in landscape mode. I would like to move the boxes outlined in the green border to just under the titles. The pink color is showing the available space given by geometry reader. Below the boxes will be some text.

The frame modifiers below the titles places the titles at the top of the pink area instead in the vertical center of the boxes. I can change the height of the boxes by changing the frame values just below the ScrollView(). Placing a Spacer() below the boxes doesn't appear to have any impact.

Any ideas?

! [See picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e4lt.png)

```
struct ShowLandCategories: View {

    var g: GeometryProxy

    var body: some View {

        VStack (alignment: .center) {
            HStack {

            // start left half of landscape screen
                ZStack {
                    Text("Current Categories")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                        .padding(.top, 5)

                ScrollView {
                    GetCurrentCats()
                }
                .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.45, height: g.size.height * 0.65, alignment: .top)
                .border(Color("Dark Green"), width: 4)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.45, height: g.size.height)

            // start right half of landscape screen
                ZStack {
                    Color.pink
                    Text("Available Categories")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                        .padding(.top, 5)

                    ScrollView {
                        GetAvailableCats()
                    }
                    .frame(width: g.size.width * 0.45, height: g.size.height * 0.65, alignment: .top)
                    .border(Color("Dark Green"), width: 4)
                }.frame(width: g.size.width * 0.45, height: g.size.height)
             }
         }
      }
   }
 


  
  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e4lt.png
```

Comment: Your screenshot link is invalid. Please [edit] and use `![landscape screenshot][1]` instead .